# Citrix application automation using QTP

Tags: qtp, citrix

I need some clarifications regarding Citrix application automation using QTP.
In my project I am having QTP 9.2 and citrix 3.5 version.

I would like to know the technical reason behind why *Citrix cannot be automated using QTP*.
Also I got information that applications in Citrix 5 can be automated using QTP.

Could you please explain (possibly with details) if the automation with Citrix 5 is effective and how it works?

Appreciate your help
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You don't really expect HP or Citrix to provide any technical reasoning about the internals of their products, do you? :)

`HP QTP` requires full access to surrounding environment (WinStation in terms of WinAPI), so that it can install hooks or otherwise query whatever information it requires to identify test objects and monitor user actions. Citrix doesn't provide API with such functionality.

It is a kind of common approach to install QTP on the Citrix Server and perform functional testing by connecting to the published desktop (much like running QTP via RDP).

It is also a popular approach to perform mix of performance and functional testing of published applications by `HP LoadRunner`, but creation and maintenance of such scripts is painful.